# MongoDB aggregate search with multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build an API for search jobs

Frontend input: single filed `keyword` with a string

API response: Return list of jobs that match any of the following fields

1. skills
2. location
3. company

**Schemas**

1.Job schema

```
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
 location: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'location',
  },
  skills:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Skill'
  }],
company: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'company',
  },
```

As you see skills, location and company are mapped in another collection and frontend gives no separation on the keyword I am not sure which way I can write an effective search query

Right now approach is

1. Find skill_id based on skill name and fetch all jobs that have desired skill

Follow the same for `location` and company

But I am not sure this is the right approach, can somebody' advise a proper way of doing this

Comment: I think I would tweak your approach a little bit. I would first get the `skill_id`s, `location_id`s and `company_id`s that match the search criteria. Then I would use those ids to create 1 query on jobs. That will have the benefit of only fetching the jobs once, and not having to worry about duplicate jobs across you multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

many strategies can be applied in your case (yours, AdamExchange's one, aggregation with $lookup stages...) depending of size of collections, indexes, etc...

But i think think you really have to look to index and [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/) strategies to really optimize your query

I would :

- first create 3 single indexes on skill.name / location.name / company indexes ===>So you can find the ids in your different collections, using index.
- Create single indexes on job collection : location, skill, company
- Then you can simply  run your queries like this (assuming MyKeyword is the value of your frontend field) [pseudo code, i don't know the language you use]:

  skillId = db.skill.find({name:MyKeyword });

  locationId = db.location.find({name:MyKeyword });

  companyId = db.company.find({name:MyKeyword });

  ```
   db.job.find({
     $or: [
       {
         skill: {
           $eq: skillId
         }
       },
       {
         location: {
           $eq: locationId
         }
       },
       {
         company: {
           $eq: companyId
         }
       }
     ]
   })
  ```

So you can take benefit of indexes to query 'secondary collections' and of indexes intersection for each case of your $or condition for main collection.

Answer (score -1):

In Mongoose, you can perform multiple field searches using the aggregation pipeline. The aggregation pipeline allows you to perform complex data transformations and queries on your MongoDB data, including searching across multiple fields. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to perform multiple field searches in Mongoose using the aggregation pipeline: